# Set $T$ is Countably Infinite

Tags: numerical-methods, cardinals

How can it be shown that

$$T = \{\,(i, j, k) \mid i, j, k \in\mathbb N\,\} $$

is countably infinite?

Comment: Have you ever heard of the Cantor Diagonalization Argument?

Comment: Since diagonalization would be used to prove something *isn't* countable, that's not relevant here.

Comment: Do you know how to show that $\mathbb Q$ is countable?

Answer (score 3):

For example, $(i,j,k)\mapsto 2^i3^j5^k$ is an injective map $T\to\mathbb N$.